# monkeyrunner doesn't handle specifical characters correctly while constructing shell commands

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

Ideally, to open the default browser and navigate to Google Maps (for Taipei 101), you can simply execute:

```
startActivity(action='android.intent.action.VIEW', data='http://maps.google.com/?q=25.033611,121.565000&z=19')
```

However, the statement doens't (always) work. After tracing monkeyrunner's source codes:

- http://androidxref.com/source/xref/sdk/monkeyrunner/src/com/android/monkeyrunner/MonkeyDevice.java#startActivity
- http://androidxref.com/source/xref/sdk/chimpchat/src/com/android/chimpchat/adb/AdbChimpDevice.java#startActivity

Here is a snippet that shows that internally monkeyrunner simply concatenate parameters literally. Please focus on #388 and #411

```
383    public void startActivity(String uri, String action, String data, String mimetype,
384            Collection<String> categories, Map<String, Object> extras, String component,
385            int flags) {
386        List<String> intentArgs = buildIntentArgString(uri, action, data, mimetype, categories,
387                extras, component, flags);
388        shell(Lists.asList("am", "start",
389                intentArgs.toArray(ZERO_LENGTH_STRING_ARRAY)).toArray(ZERO_LENGTH_STRING_ARRAY));
390    }
...
406    private List<String> buildIntentArgString(String uri, String action, String data, String mimetype,
407            Collection<String> categories, Map<String, Object> extras, String component,
408            int flags) {
409        List<String> parts = Lists.newArrayList();
410
411        // from adb docs:
412        //<INTENT> specifications include these flags:
413        //    [-a <ACTION>] [-d <DATA_URI>] [-t <MIME_TYPE>]
414        //    [-c <CATEGORY> [-c <CATEGORY>] ...]
415        //    [-e|--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE> ...]
416        //    [--esn <EXTRA_KEY> ...]
417        //    [--ez <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_BOOLEAN_VALUE> ...]
418        //    [-e|--ei <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE> ...]
419        //    [-n <COMPONENT>] [-f <FLAGS>]
420        //    [<URI>]
421
422        if (!isNullOrEmpty(action)) {
423            parts.add("-a");
424            parts.add(action);
425        }
426
427        if (!isNullOrEmpty(data)) {
428            parts.add("-d");
429            parts.add(data);
430        }
...
479        return parts;
480    }
```

For this case, the following shell command will be executed.

```
$ am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://maps.google.com/?q=25.033611,121.565000&z=19
$ Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://maps.google.com/?q=25.033611,121.565000 }

[1]   Done                    am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://maps.google.com/?q=25.033611,121.565000
```

You may find that the root cause is the ampersand (&). It is interpreted specially in the shell enviroment, that is executing preceding command in the background.

To avoid this misinterpretation, we can escape that special character by prefixing \ to it.

```
$ am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://maps.google.com/?q=25.033611,121.565000\&z=19
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://maps.google.com/?q=25.033611,121.565000&z=19 }
```

Therefore, in monkeyrunner, you should escape parameter values before passing them into `startActivity` (or even other `MonkeyDevice` methods), to circumvent this problem.

```
startActivity(action='android.intent.action.VIEW', data=r'http://maps.google.com/?q=25.033611,121.565000\&z=19')
```

Finally, it works!! However, I think monkeyrunner, as a friendly API, should do this escaping internally. How do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are absolutely right. The way I found of circumventing this an other nuisances is to use

```
device.shell('am start ...')
```

where at least you know what to expect.

Comment: Yes. However, It seems like a workaround to fall back to use shell commands immediately. There should be someone else encounters this issue. Do you know where I can officially submit a ticket?